# Typescript type is has `any` type in function body, but it OK in outside scope

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Why do types inside function bodies return `any` type, but their type is available in outside scope?

```
const locationState = useLocation<navigationProps>().state || {};
//locationState is string | undefined
```

Ok, works here with no type error

```
console.log(locationState)
```

but fails here in function body

```
function doSomething() {
  console.log(locationState)
}
```

> Variable 'locationState' implicitly has an 'any' type.

HERE IS AN EXAMPLE THAT IS FAILING:

`useLocation` is from React-Router.

```
export type navigationPropsWithPassedEvent = {
  type: "eventProps";
  processEvent?: boolean;
  eventId?: number;
};

export type navigationPropsWithAlert = {
  type: "alertProps";
  showNotice: boolean;
  noticetype: "success" | "error";
  message: string;
  description: string;
};

export type navigationPropsWithFormVal = {
  type: "formProps";
  roleName: string;
  accountNumber: string;
  setupMethod: SetupMethod;
};

export type navigationProps = navigationPropsWithAlert | navigationPropsWithPassedEvent | navigationPropsWithFormVal;


const ProcessingPage: React.FC<RouteProps> = () => {
   let noticetype, showNotice, message, description, processEvent, eventId, roleName, accountNumber;
   const locationState = useLocation<navigationProps>().state || {};


  if (locationState.type === "formProps") {
    ({ roleName, accountNumber } = locationState);
  }

  if (locationState.type === "alertProps") {
    ({ noticetype, showNotice, message, description } = locationState);
  }

  if (locationState.type === "eventProps") {
    ({ processEvent, eventId } = locationState);
  }
  
  console.log(processEvent)
  // ok this working

  function someFunc() {
    console.log(processEvent)
    //this fails with 
    // Variable 'processEvent' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  }
...
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://tsplay.dev/m0n4Dw. And what is `useLocation`? What is `navigationProps`? Please [edit] your question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the type errors.

Comment: the [mcve] you're looking for is https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/DYUwLgBADgTg9gYxAZ2QUQG4gHZgNwCwAUAnNsnKAHTBwDmAFLIiulrgJSFEBmArtgRgAlmQg84cBhwDexCBFLlKIGvSbwkqTDjBdiAXyA - the issue would be the `let` without type, not sure why it works in one spot but not the other though. I guess it cannot be sure anymore since it could have been changed once the function is called so it's just implicitly any.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simple version:

```
let foo

console.log(foo) // no error

function bar() {
  console.log(foo) // error
}
```

When you use `foo` outside the function, Typescript knows what's been assigned to it, which is nothing. So typescript knows the variable's value is `undefined`. If you mouse over `foo` in that spot, it will tell you the type is `undefined`. And because you didn't define a type, the type was "implicit any", which got narrowed to `undefined` since you never assigned it.

However, when you use it in a function, that value could have been replaced by another value before this function is called. Typescript has no way of knowing when this function gets called. So the type narrowing to `undefined` is lost, and you're left with just the "implicit any" which you aren't allowed to use.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jCwAoJBjGA7AzjUA6YMA5gBSwwCUEA9FROjBCAE5MxNJJQCu6KYAlhggAjAIZNilAN5IIENFhwh8RUnEo1GLNkgC+QA)

---

That's the why, but the solution is just to not allow implicit any in the first place. Give the variable a type and there's no problem.

```
let foo: string | undefined

console.log(foo) // no error

function bar() {
  console.log(foo) // no error
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jBcEDOYBOBLAdgcwgHwgFdMATEKLEEgWACg6BjGTJGUAOmBmwApYYAlBAD0wiJhgQQqVDFR06UYgzDpmEAEYBDVDyEBvOhAhMWbEJ2584Q0eMnTZ82gF8gA)